# Bonfire Codeigniter htaccess to set root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, bonfire

I have a site in Bonfire Codeigniter (PHP) and I have to move it to a server but I do not have access to the virtual hosts.

I need to solve this problem but I must use htaccess instead.

Can anyone help me please?

**Your Web Root should be set to the public folder, but it's not. It's pointing to the Bonfire Root folder.
See below for an example of how your site should be set up in Apache:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "[...]/htdocs/Bonfire_Root/public"
    ServerName Bonfire.Root
    ServerAlias Bonfire.Root.local
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried with **RewriteBase public/** but as you can imagine, It did not work.